# Shiny not displaying my ggplot as I'd expect

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

What's keeping my little Shiny app from displaying my ggplot?  When I replace the code in renderPlot() with an example using the base plot function it comes together. I'm using RStudio, R v3.0.1 on Windows Vista, outputting to a Chrome browser.

**ui.r**

```
library(ggplot2)

cities <- c("Anchorage","Fairbanks","Juenau","Wasilla","Homer")
years <- 2003:2013
Table <- "Capital Assets"
Account <- c("Land", "Art", "Buildings", "Equipment")
dat <- data.frame(City = sort(rep(cities, length(years))), Year = rep(years,length(cities)), Table)
sampleDat <- rbind(data.frame(dat,Acount = Account[1]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[2]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[3]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[4]))
finalDat <- data.frame(sampleDat, Value = runif(length(sampleDat[,1]), 1000,10000) )

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("CAFR Explorer"),

  selectInput("city","City", as.list(levels(finalDat$City)), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE),

  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),

    plotOutput("CAFRplot")
)))
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

cities <- c("Anchorage","Fairbanks","Juenau","Wasilla","Homer")
years <- 2003:2013
Table <- "Capital Assets"
Account <- c("Land", "Art", "Buildings", "Equipment")
dat <- data.frame(City = sort(rep(cities, length(years))), Year = rep(years,length(cities)), Table)
sampleDat <- rbind(data.frame(dat,Acount = Account[1]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[2]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[3]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[4]))
finalDat <- data.frame(sampleDat, Value = runif(length(sampleDat[,1]), 1000,10000) )

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste(input$city)
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  output$CAFRplot <- renderPlot({

    ## this one isn't working.
    ggplot(finalDat, aes(x = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),2], 
                         y = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),5])) +
    geom_point()

    ## this one is working
    #plot(finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),2], y = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),5])


  })
})
```

Comment: try wrapping you ggplot call in `print` ie `print(ggplot(...) + geom_point)`

Comment: You should show the error message you're getting instead of just saying "isn't working."  Jake is right that you should wrap print around your ggplot call, but I think there is something else wrong with your ggplot call (scoping issue).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, you shouldn't subset in `aes` -- it expects column names.  Instead, subset the data.frame that you provide to `ggplot` (thanks to @Roland from R chat)

Second, you must explicitly `print` your ggplot object in your shiny app.

Try this:

```
p <- ggplot(finalDat[finalDat$City == input$city,], aes(x = Year, y = Value))
p <- p + geom_point()
print(p)
```

Comment: +1 Nice and elegant. I hadn't seen your response, or I wouldn't have typed mine.

Answer (score 3):

Your code needed a couple of changes to get `ggplot` to render. As the comments above state, `print(ggplot)` was needed. But also, aes inside ggplot can't deal with subsetting.

So you subset your city of interest in a separate reactive, and call that from ggplot.

```
city.df <- reactive({
    subset(finalDat, City == input$city)
  })  

  output$CAFRplot <- renderPlot({
    city <- city.df()

    print(ggplot(city, aes(x = Year, y=Value)) + geom_point())
```

**The full server.R (this works)**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

cities <- c("Anchorage","Fairbanks","Juenau","Wasilla","Homer")
years <- 2003:2013
Table <- "Capital Assets"
Account <- c("Land", "Art", "Buildings", "Equipment")
dat <- data.frame(City = sort(rep(cities, length(years))), Year = rep(years,length(cities)), Table)
sampleDat <- rbind(data.frame(dat,Acount = Account[1]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[2]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[3]), data.frame(dat, Acount = Account[4]))
finalDat <- data.frame(sampleDat, Value = runif(length(sampleDat[,1]), 1000,10000) )

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste(input$city)
  })

  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })

  city.df <- reactive({
    subset(finalDat, City == input$city)
  })  

  output$CAFRplot <- renderPlot({
    city <- city.df()
    ## this one isn't working.
#    print(ggplot(finalDat, aes(x = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),2], 
#                         y = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),5])) +  geom_point())

    print(ggplot(city, aes(x = Year, y=Value)) + geom_point())

    ## this one is working
    #plot(finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),2], y = finalDat[which(finalDat$City == input$city),5])


  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In  `ggplot2`  you can subset the overall data being passed to all layers (@GSee's answer) or, for indivdual layers you can use the `subset` argument to subset  just for that layer. This may be useful if you are constructing more complex plots.

Using the `plyr` function `.` is useful here for constructing the arguments

```
# required in server.R (along with the other calls to library)
library(plyr)

 p <- ggplot(finalDat, aes(y =Year, x = Value)) + 
        geom_point(subset = .(City ==input$city))
 print(p)
```