# Subsetting data in Shiny to create interactive ggplot barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to build my first shiny app that lets users explore different types of parking violations in Copenhagen. But i'm having difficulties subsetting data to be plottet based on user input - basically i'm trying to create an interactive version of the plot below where the user can select type_1,type_2, etc.

```
#example data
df <- data.frame(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), c(rep_len(55, 5), 0, 44),c(rep_len(12, 5), 6, 6), c(0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 7, 8), c(0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 5, 3), c(5, 0, 6, 0, 11,12, 9))
names(df) <- c("street", "type_1", "type_2", "type_3", "type_4", "type_5")

#Example of static plot that i'm trying to make interactive
ggplot(subset(df, type_5 > 5))+geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(street,type_5), y=type_5),stat = "identity")+coord_flip()+xlab("Streetname")
```

[image]

My ui.R and server.R are as follows. My original data has over 2000 streetnames which is why i'm trying to subset the data to include only parking violations of type_x > some treshold

```
# Define the overall UI
ui <- shinyUI(

# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    

# Give the page a title
titlePanel("Parking violations"),

# Generate a row with a sidebar
sidebarLayout(      

  # Define the sidebar with one input
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("type", "Type of violation:", 
                choices=colnames(df), selected = "type_1" ),
    hr(),
    helpText("Data from Parking Copenhagen")
  ),

  # Create a spot for the barplot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("pplot")  
  )

)
)
)



# Define a server for the Shiny app
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Subset the data based on user input
  p.df <- reactive({
    subset(df, input$type > 5)
  })  


  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$pplot <- renderPlot({

    pdat.df <- p.df()

    # Render a barplot
    p <- ggplot(pdat.df, aes(x=pdat.df$street, y=input$type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+coord_flip()

    print(p)

  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

The result below is not quite what I was looking for. I have tried the options suggested here [shiny not displaying my ggplot as I'd expect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038947/shiny-not-displaying-my-ggplot-as-id-expect/18039004#18039004) but no luck with either subsetting within `ggplot()`(as in my static example) or `geom_bar()`

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I can't test your code, but maybe it related to "input$type > 5" and "choices=colnames(df), selected = "type_1"" is type_1 a factor? because you filter a number.

Comment: type_1-5 is numerical,so I assume thats not the problem?

Comment: or maybe in you reactive() expression df <- subset(df, input$type > 5); df

Comment: @MLavoie that doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: before posting as answer try to replace by p <- ggplot(pdat.df, aes_string(x=pdat.df$street, y=input$type))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `subset(df, input$type > 5)` on `return( df[df[input$type]>5,])`

because input return `character` and `subset` cant interprent it as `colname`
for example ( with your data)

```
subset(df,"type_1">5)
    #  street type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5
    #1      a     55     12      0      0      5
    #2      b     55     12      2      0      0
    #3      c     55     12      0      4      6
    #4      d     55     12      3      0      0
    #5      e     55     12      0      8     11
    #6      f      0      6      7      5     12
    #7      g     44      6      8      3      9

df[df["type_1"]>5,]
    #  street type_1 type_2 type_3 type_4 type_5
    #1      a     55     12      0      0      5
    #2      b     55     12      2      0      0
    #3      c     55     12      0      4      6
    #4      d     55     12      3      0      0
    #5      e     55     12      0      8     11
    #7      g     44      6      8      3      9
```

(6-th row subseted)

i not see reorder in yor shiny version 
try

```
pdat.df <- p.df()
pdat.df$street=reorder(pdat.df$street,pdat.df[[input$type]])
```

and as @MLavoie told

```
aes_string(x="street", y=input$type)
```